# Set Database Properties when creating it with SqlDatabase.createAsync()

Tags: azure-java-sdk

This is the question about the  Azure Management Libraries for Java.

First, some background:

The Azure Management REST API mentions at the [createorupdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate) definition the ability to create the database and set different database properties like this (example from the page):

```
{
  "location": "southeastasia",
  "sku": {
    "name": "S0",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createMode": "Default",
    "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
    "maxSizeBytes": 1073741824
  }
}
```

I'm looking how to do the similar request from the [Azure Management Libraries for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java).

So far I have found how to set the "sku" part. This is done by using the appropriate [ServiceObjectiveName](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-sql/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/sql/ServiceObjectiveName.java) object:

```
final SqlServer sqlServer = ...get SQL server object ...;

final Creatable<SqlDatabase> myDb = sqlServer.databases()
            .define(targetDBName)
            .withServiceObjective(ServiceObjectiveName.fromString("S0"));
...

myDb.createAsync(...); // create the db with sku S0
```

But I can't figure out how to set the properties. For my purpose I need to set a bit different properties than in the sample. Namely, the specific `properties.maxSizeBytes` and `properties.autoPauseDelay`.

I even found the `.withMaxSizeBytes()` method [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-sql/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/sql/SqlDatabaseOperations.java#L559) but it's marked deprecated without any explanation.

I haven't found any way to set the `autoPauseDelay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By digging in the [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sql/resource-manager/v2018_06_01_preview/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/sql/v2018_06_01_preview), I am sorry that I did not find any methods for setting these properties.

The complicated workaround I think of is to use resource deployment. It is supported in java sdk:

```
azure.deployments().define(deploymentName)
        .withExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
        .withTemplate(templateJson)
        .withParameters("{}")
        .withMode(DeploymentMode.INCREMENTAL)
        .create();
```

And here is a sample which can give you some guidance: [DeployUsingARMTemplate](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-java-deploy-using-arm-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/samples/DeployUsingARMTemplate.java)

By the way, you can try to create a database on Azure portal, and then you can download the template at the last step of the creation:

[image]